# F# strange difference in resolving class method calls

Tags: f#

Given the following F# code

```
type MyClass = class end

type MyWorker1() = 
    (*1*)member this.DoWork(myObject: MyClass) = ()
    (*2*)member this.DoWork(myObjects: MyClass seq) = myObjects |> Seq.iter this.DoWork //Resolves to (*1*)

type MyWorker2() = 
    (*3*)member this.DoWork(myObject: #MyClass) = ()
    (*4*)member this.DoWork(myObjects: #MyClass seq) = myObjects |> Seq.iter this.DoWork //Resolves to (*4*)
```

in MyWorker2 the call this.DoWork is resolved as recursive call. I expected to behave as in MyWorker1, that is call (*3*).

**Can someone explain the reason for this difference?**

Comment: This looks like an F# compiler bug to me. I would report it.

Comment: reported https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/13769

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already reported by [@Gus on Slack](https://fsharp.slack.com/archives/C05325FDM/p1661323833210429), this is likely a bug, good you reported it! Note that it appears to happen only with `seq`, not with other collection types like `array` or `list`. It also doesn't happen when you use `let` bindings instead of `member` or `static member`.

This is probably because `let` bindings cannot be self-referential unless you add `rec`. By adding `rec`, you actually do see the same behavior again, but this time it is expected.

I'm surprised that F# adds an extra constraint as `'a :> seq<'a>`, I find this really odd.

Since this is SO, and I'm gonna assume this blocks a certain pattern of coding, here's a workaround. It's a little extra indirection, but if you need the above pattern in real world code, here's how you can do it:

```
type MyWorker2() = 
    let doWork1(myObject: #MyClass) = ()
    let doWork2(myObjects: seq<#MyClass>) = myObjects |> Seq.iter (fun x -> doWork1 x) //Resolves to (*4*)

    member this.DoWork(myObject: #MyClass) = doWork1 myObject
    member this.DoWork(myObjects: seq<#MyClass>) = doWork2 myObjects
```

One observation, if you make the private `let`-bindings the same name (i.e. just `doWork` instead of `doWork1|2`), the issue with the extra type restriction appears on the first `DoWork`. But this time it makes sense, as the let-bindings shadow one another.